# Using $q.all sometimes causes selects to not read the model correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I noticed that one of my select dropdowns would occasionally not have the correct item selected from the Angular model. I traced it down to be what appears an issue with promises not fulfilling before Angular loads the form. After trying a large amount of different methods, I finally decided to do this non-sense to make it work:

```
$q.all([
    $scope.categories.$promise,
    $scope.durations.$promise,
    $scope.job.$promise,
    $scope.jobStatuses.$promise,
    $scope.recruiters.$promise,
    $scope.states.$promise
]).then(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.editJob = {
            acceptsVisas: $scope.job.acceptsVisas,
            categoryId: $scope.job.categoryID,
            city: $scope.job.city,
            contact: $scope.job.contactID,
            description: $scope.job.details,
            duration: $scope.job.durationID,
            internalId: $scope.job.internalReqID,
            postal: $scope.job.postal,
            recruiter: $scope.job.recruiterID,
            state: $scope.job.stateID,
            status: $scope.job.jobStatusID,
            title: $scope.job.title
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Without the setTimeout, the select will occasionally not the wrong recruiter selected. I've debugged it down to something inside Angular/JS. Examining the model shows that the right fields are set before hand, and it's not reliably reproducible, which leads me to the assumption that Angular is loading the form before the promise is finished, and then not selecting the right recruiter when it loads the recruiter data. Nothing is being set out of context, this is pretty much all the code aside from the queries being ran on the resources. I also updated the `windows.setTimeout` to use `$timeout`, but the main point of needing to do it in the first place remains.

Comment: use $timeout instead of setTimeout

Comment: Without looking in too much depth, this is likely to be an issue with your `$scope.editJob` being set outside of the Angular context i.e. it's being set during promise resolution. The comment above this makes note of `$timeout`. If you wrap the set of `editJob` in a `$timeout`, this hack will bring your code back into Angular scope.

Comment: @JamieDixon: `$q` is an Angular service. Code within `then` is 'inside' of Angular. Code within `window.setTimeout` not so much.

Comment: @JamieDixon - I had thought that was the issue, so I removed any calling of `$scope.editJob` aside from that. I could possibly change it to $timeout, but my complaint is that I shouldn't have to do the timeout, because I would assume Angular would pick up the correct model value and make the select have that value selected.

Comment: What is triggering the above code? If in a directive you may need to call `$apply` to trigger a digest cycle even if everything is "within angular". An mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help us find a more suitable answer

Comment: It was in a controller.

Comment: Additionally, it's long since been refactored out. We added in the ui-router and broke up those calls a bit more. After that the timeout wasn't needed. I did try to `$apply` back then, too, but no dice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A year later, and I've found no answer. For all the searching I've done since then, it seems like the simple answer is that it's a flaw in Angular, and there really isn't much to do about it. The timeout solution works, it just shouldn't be needed. Unfortunately, that's the side-effect of third-party software.

Comment: To whomever provided the downvote from me answering my own question: do you have a solution? How is the answer wrong? I'm still looking for an answer other than "it's just broken" if you got one.